# Is it possible to switch between terminal windows like you do in osx

Tags: gnome-terminal

does anybody knows if it's possible to switch between terminal windows  like you do in OSX. (Cmd + "Terminal Number")?

For instance, let's say you've open three terminal windows, when you press Cmd + 1, "terminal number 1" gets activated, when you press Cmd + 2, "terminal number two gets activated", and so on...

PS: I know that this is possible if you are using tabs, but I want to use different windows.

Thanks!

Comment: The only way that I am aware of to switch between `terminals` or like applications that have more than one window open is to use Super+Tab key combination when you are on the application you want to switch between.

Comment: Hi @Terrance, in ubuntu you can switch between windows/instances of the same application by pressing Super + tilde. But if you are in terminal number 1 and want to go to terminal number 4, you are forced to go 2,3,4. Is OSX you can press Cmd+4 and that's about it. Thanks anyways!

Comment: So that depends really on the desktop version you are running.  I run Xfce4 and Super + Tilde does absolutely nothing.  The problem you're bumping into here is that Ubuntu does not number the terminal Windows so they're is no way for a command like they have on Mac to do that.  Or if a terminal that I'm aware of that supports that type of function.

Comment: I think that might by the case... And as far as I can tell, there's no terminal supporting that behavior (At least, I couldn't find any....). I'll keep looking, though. Thanks!